# Combinatoric task about game

Tags: combinatorics, balls-in-bins

There is a small town in old times. And there was one interesting game.

Consider $N$ people playing this game. Every evening they are getting together
to play this game. Every evening exactly $N$ people come to play.

Game rules: everybody chooses random integer number from $1$ to $F$: $1,2,3,...,F$. $F$ is a constant value and never changes. So, $k$ persons write chosen number on the paper and name. There is some probability of participation. I mean with probability $\tau$ person will play this game.

Then they collect papers. They look at the numbers. If I choose number that nobody except me choose than I win this game. There could be multiply winners.

Example. $N = 6$, $F = 4$ and then $k=6$ that day then if

A wrote $3$,

B wrote $2$,

C wrote $3$,

D wrote $4$,

E wrote $2$,

F wrote $1$, then F and D won that game  that day and every winner get 100 gold.

**QUESTIONS**

1. I ask you too find the expected number of winners per day. (solved)
2. And the hardest question is to find out the optimal $\tau$ in order to maximize expected number of winners. let's think that habitats are smart and try to use this optimal $\tau$ in order to get as much gold as possible.

My solution:

1. Let's take a look on one day. I can choose $k$ people with $\binom N k$ ways of doing it. Lets think that these people will play and another $N-k$ will not.

So now we have 
$$
\sum_{k=0}^{N} \binom N k \tau^k (1-\tau)^{N-k} \cdot smth
$$

Then let's deal with smth.

Lets $B(m,k,F)$ -- number of ways to write a random numbers, which are $\le F$ so that exactly $m$ persons are winners among $k$ people.

I can compute this number correctly.

Then I think that probability of winning of exactly $m$ persons is $$\frac{B(m,k,F)}{\sum_{m} B(m,k,F)}$$

Now I think that desirable thing is equal to the following:

$$
\sum_{k=0}^{N} \binom N k \tau^k (1-\tau)^{N-k} \cdot \sum_{m=0}^{k}m\cdot\frac{B(m,k,F)}{\sum_{m} B(m,k,F)}
$$

And another answer to this problem you can see in the comments.

2. But for should I do for optimal $\tau$? Derivative gives nothing.

Comment: The linearity of expectation is particularly powerful in problems like these.  Ask yourself first the question, what is the probability that person $A$ wins the game?

Comment: @JMoravitz This probabilty is $$p_{suc }= \sum\limits_{k=0}^{N-1}\binom{N-1}{k}\tau^{k}(1-\tau)^{N-k-1} \left(1-\frac{1}{F}\right)^k  = \tau \left(1-\frac{\tau}{F}\right)^{N-1}$$

Comment: @JMoravitz Do you want to say that it is just 
$$
\sum_{j=0}^{N} j \cdot \binom N j p_{suc} ^j (1-p_{suc})^{N-j}
$$

It seems to me that it is wrong too.

Comment: And I want to use number $B(m,k,F)$ in my answer as well. Hehe. There was a hint from a teacher to use it

Comment: @JMoravitz oh, I find out that these two answers that we have, are equal.

Comment: @JMoravitz I forgot to put the second question. Pls, see update.